# UnauthorizedAccessException - DeleteAsync StorageFile

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I am storing files in ObservableCollection (FileItem contains StorageFile File). In GridView I bind to this collection and I display images with handling ContainerContentChaning event.

```
     private async void GridView_ContainerContentChanging(ListViewBase sender, ContainerContentChangingEventArgs args)
    {
        var item = args.Item as IImageProvider;
        var imageParent = args.ItemContainer.ContentTemplateRoot as Border;
        var imageControl = imageParent.Child as Image;
        ...
        imageControl.Source = await item.GetImage(ImageSizeType.Thumbnail);
    }
```

I also have command to delete files - which is something like that:

```
     images.Remove(item);
     await item.PerformStorageFileOperation(async (file) =>
     {
          await file.DeleteAsync(StorageDeleteOption.PermanentDelete);
     }, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);
```

where item is FileItem and PerformStorageFileOperation looks like that:

```
  public async Task PerformStorageFileOperation(Func<StorageFile, Task> operation, CancellationToken cancelToken)
{
    await _syncLock.WaitAsync(cancelToken);
    await operation(File);
    _syncLock.Release();
}
```

SyncLock is SemphoreSlim. Both `.GetImage` and Delete file functions uses PerfomStorageFileOperation so I guess there is no chance both methods uses StorageFile on the same time. GetImage gets Image from byte[] - there is no setting/binding BitmapImage source to any file stream. Occasionally I gets UnathorizedAccessException - however I doubt it is caused by insufficient file priviligies and things like that because I can get 3 times exception while deleting and on say fourth time the same file is deleted correctly.

Comment: Since you are deleting `async` could the file being deleted still be in use which is triggering the `UnathorizedAccessException`?

Comment: well the point is the only place where I use file is .GetImage method - which calls PerformsStorageOperation. This method load thumbnail using file.GetThumbnailAsync() to get image byte array and then I dispose this new file stream. Bindings are done to File model but never to StorageFile so I have no idea where it could be used.

Comment: Another process (like anti virus) may be using the file. You can Windows Performance Recorder / Analyzer to see which process are using the file when the exception occurs.

Comment: @Tristan can you please provide some tutorial how to use WPR/A to find that?